# Equation with inverse trigonometric functions and logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Solve over reals
>
> $$\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arcsin\, \{x\}\right)+\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arccos\,\{x\}\right)=\frac{2}{\log_\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\arctan e^{\lfloor x\rfloor} + \operatorname{arccot} e^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)}$$
>
> where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ the
>   floor function.

For the left side I have

$$\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arcsin\, \{x\}\right)+\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arccos\,\{x\}\right)=\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arcsin\, \{x\}\cdot \arccos\,\{x\}\right)$$

but I don't know what to do with the right side and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What is the relationship between $\arctan x$ and $\operatorname{arccot} x$ for all real $x$?

Comment: @dnfu. I found online that $\arctan x +\operatorname{arccot} x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. But still, I am stuck at $\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arcsin\, \{x\}\cdot \arccos\,\{x\}\right) = \frac{2}{\log_\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\pi}{2}}$. Also, will this question be closed? (I don't know what I did wrong).

Comment: Recall that $0\leq \{x\} < 1$. Considering this, what is the relationship between $\arcsin \{ x\}$ and $\arccos \{ x\}$? Also $\log_a b = \frac1{\log_b a}$.

Comment: I have no idea why the question has been downvoted, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would proceed.

We have
$$\arccos\{x\} = \frac{\pi}2 - \arcsin\{x\}$$
and
$$\arctan e^{\lfloor x \rfloor}+\operatorname{arccot} e^{\lfloor x \rfloor}=\frac{\pi}2.$$

Therefore your equation is equivalent to
$$\log_{\pi/2}\left[\arcsin\{x\}\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arcsin\{x\}\right)\right]=\frac{2}{\log_{\pi/4}\frac{\pi}2}.$$
Recall now that $\log_a b\cdot \log_b a =1$ and write then
$$\log_{\pi/2}\left[\arcsin\{x\}\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arcsin\{x\}\right)\right]=\log_{\pi/2}\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)^2.$$
Equating the logarithm arguments yields then
$$\arcsin\{x\}\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arcsin\{x\}\right)= \frac{\pi^2}{16}$$
Or equivalently
\begin{eqnarray}\arcsin^2\{x\}-\frac{\pi}2\arcsin\{x\}+\frac{\pi^2}{16}&=&0\\
\left(\arcsin\{x\}-\frac{\pi}4\right)^2 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
which leads to 
$$\{x\} = \frac1{\sqrt 2},$$
i.e.
$$x = k + \frac1{\sqrt 2}, \ \ k\in \Bbb Z.$$

Comment: Thank you, I found something similar: $\log_\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arcsin\, \{x\}\cdot \arccos\,\{x\}\right) = \log_\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{\arcsin\, \{x\}+ \arccos\,\{x\}}{2}\right)^2$$ \implies \arcsin\, \{x\}\cdot \arccos\,\{x\}= \left(\frac{\arcsin\, \{x\}+ \arccos\,\{x\}}{2}\right)^2 \implies$$  \left(\arcsin\, \{x\}- \arccos\,\{x\}\right)^2=0\implies \arcsin\, \{x\}= \arccos\,\{x\} \implies \{x\}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$